# How to set different UI for different screens

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS development and lack experience. I'm wondering is there any way to design UI for both iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 screens simultaneously? I have drawn my iPhone5 version UI using storyboard. But when I switch to 3.5-inch screen, everything becomes a mess.

I tried to use autolayout, but it seems only support set some fixed number, but what I want is changing the size proportionally.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial, it will help you [Beginning Auto Layout in iOS 6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)